# How to Edit CMPixelBuffer by pixel

Tags: ios, swift, cvpixelbuffer

I'm an undergraduate student and I'm programming some HumanSeg iPhone app. Now I have to read raw frames from the camera, but I found the codes in official guide aren't clear enough for me to understand.

When I get the frames (in `CMPixelBuffer` format) from the camera, I need to modify it (I mean I have to do some ***padding*** and ***resizing***, and turn it into a `CVPixelBuffer` format, to feed it to a CoreML MobileNet).

I've been searching for the solution for weeks, but unfortunately I got nothing. In the offical guide I was told that these buffers "doen't offer direct access to inner data".

I even tried to use a `Context` to draw the `CMPixelBuffer` into a `UIImage` and draw it back to a `CVPixelBuffer`，and I found this process terribly slow, just as the offcial guide says. Since I'm doing video processing this method is unacceptable.

What am I supposed to do or read? I really appreciate your help.